# Python doesn't retrieve data from mysql table

Tags: mysql, xampp, python-3.7

I am tried to retrieve entry_time from mysql table (named user) and then find the time difference between now (exitTime) and the entry_time. My code doesn't seem to recover the data from mysql table. f is the id search key for the code which searches against the ID (PRIMARY KEY) of the mysql database to find the corresponding entry_time.

I have tried taking it as a string as well to see if i could retrieve the value but to no avail.

```
from tkinter import *
import time,datetime
import mysql.connector as mc
from tkinter import messagebox
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plt
import sys
import time





def billCalc():
    global exitTime
    global EntryTime
    EntryTime = datetime.datetime
    exitTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        conn = mc.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='car_park_master')

    except mc.Error as e:
        print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        sys.exit(1)


        sql_Query = "SELECT `entry_time` FROM `user` WHERE `ID` ="+f.get()
        #id = (f.get(),)
        print(record[1])
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        cursor.execute(sql_Query, id)
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        # selecting column value into varible
        EntryTime = datetime(record[1])
        print(record[1])




    conn.close()
    print(exitTime)
    print(EntryTime)
    print(f.get())
    BillTime = EntryTime - exitTime
    Bill = BillTime * 2
    print(Bill.get())




def main_screen():





    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x400")
    screen.title("EXIT GATE")


    global f
    f = StringVar()

    Entry(screen, textvariable=f).place(x=150, y=200)

    print(f.get())


    Button(screen,text="Exit",height='2',width='15',command=billCalc).place(x=150,y=300)
    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

It is supposed to take an exit time using datetime.datetime.now() which it does. 
Then it is supposed to take input ID from the user to search in the database.
After that it is supposed to retrieve the corresponding entry time
Find the difference between entrytime and exit time in seconds
Then provide a bill.

EDITED AND FIXED CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import mysql.connector as mc
from tkinter import messagebox
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plt
import sys
import time






def billCalc():
    global exitTime
    global EntryTime
    EntryTime = datetime.datetime
    exitTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        conn = mc.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='car_park_master')

    except mc.Error as e:
        print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
        sys.exit(1)



    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT entry_time FROM user where id="+f.get())
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    EntryTime = (record[0])



    conn.close()
    print(exitTime)
    print(EntryTime)
    print(f.get())

    BillTime = exitTime - EntryTime


    print(BillTime)




def main_screen():





    screen = Tk()
    screen.geometry("300x400")
    screen.title("EXIT GATE")


    global f
    f = StringVar()

    Entry(screen, textvariable=f).place(x=150, y=200)

    print(f.get())


    Button(screen,text="Exit",height='2',width='15',command=billCalc).place(x=150,y=300)
    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: Errorcode

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Comment out this line: EntryTime = datetime(record[1]) and show what record[0] is. I bet you have a dictionary nested inside of a tuple which is why you are getting the tuple index error: the tuple has only one element within it.

Comment: I was tired and frustrated and seem to have made many silly errors in my code. I have posted a fixed code. You are correct! Thank you!